# Webscraping using BeautifulSoup (Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

Good afternoon,

I am fairly new to Webscraping. I am trying to scrape a dataset from an open source portal. Just to try to figure out how I can scrape website.
I am trying to scape a dataset from data.toerismevlaanderen.be
This is the dataset i want: https://data.toerismevlaanderen.be/tourist/reca/beer_bars

I always end up with a http error: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

This is my code:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://data.toerismevlaanderen.be/'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
soup.findAll('a')
one_a_tag = soup.findAll('a')[35]
link = one_a_tag['href']

download_url = 'https://data.toerismevlaanderen.be/'+ link
urllib.request.urlretrieve(download_url,'./'+link[link.find('/tourist/reca/beer_bars_')+1:]) 

time.sleep
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you specify which part of the website you want to scrape? If I use your code, I get the error that `one_a_tag = soup.findAll('a')[35]` it is out-of-list.

Comment: Sorry the 35 needs to be 1

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the following:

```
link = one_a_tag['href']
print(link)
```

This returns a link: `https://data.toerismevlaanderen.be/`

Then you are adding this `link` to `download_url` by doing:

```
download_url = 'https://data.toerismevlaanderen.be/'+ link
```

Therefore, if you `print(download_url)`, you get:

```
https://data.toerismevlaanderen.be/https://data.toerismevlaanderen.be/
```

Which it is not a valid url.

**UPDATE BASED ON COMMENTS**

The issue is that there is not `tourist/activities/breweries` anywhere in the text you scrape.
If you write:

```
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
  print(link.get('href'))
```

you see all the a href tag. None contains `tourist/activities/breweries`

**But**
If you want just the link `data.toerismevlaanderen.be/tourist/activities/breweries` you can do:

```
download_url = link + "tourist/activities/breweries"
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwer. I understand what you are saying.  But how do I change the code?   I ha ve to remove + link in download_url. How do I change the urllib.request?

Comment: Can you tell what is the final output you want? Maybe the `download_url` ideally you want

Comment: For example: i want this dataset: https://data.toerismevlaanderen.be/tourist/activities/breweries

Comment: So do you want all the `a tags` such as: `"https://data.toerismevlaanderen.be/newsletter/subscribe` or `https://data.toerismevlaanderen.be/contact/contact`?

Comment: No, that is not necessary. Only the datasets would be enough

Comment: The issue is that there is not `tourist/activities/breweries` anywhere in the text you scrape. If you write: `for link in soup.findAll('a'):
  print(link.get('href'))` you see all the `a href` tag. If you want just the link `data.toerismevlaanderen.be/tourist/activities/breweries` you can do: `download_url = link + "tourist/activities/breweries"`

Comment: Perfect, I updated my original answer. If it satisfies your question, please select it.

Answer (score 1):

There is [an API](https://data.toerismevlaanderen.be/tourist/reca/beer_bars) for this so I would use that

e.g.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://opendata.visitflanders.org/tourist/reca/beer_bars.json?page=1&page_size=500&limit=1').json()
```

Answer (score 0):

you get many absolute links in return. Adding it to the original url for new requests therefor won't work. Simply requesting the 'link' you grabbed will work instead